# (Linux) How to get initial position of mouse or set cursor position without x in c?

Tags: c, linux, mouseevent

I am going to get Mouse Position in Console.

But x/y is about movement. So I have to calculate position.
There's an way to get with X, but I am using framebuffer in my program, so I want how to get without X.

I got movement with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MOUSEDEV "/dev/input/event0"
//#pragma pack(1)

int filedesc;

int x, y;

void readm(){
    struct input_event in;
    read(filedesc, &in, sizeof(struct input_event)); /* there was data to read */
    if(in.type == 3)
    printf("Input: Time: %d.%d Type: %d Code: %d Value: %d\n", in.time.tv_sec, in.time.tv_usec, in.type, in.code, in.value);
    usleep(1000);
}

int main(){
    filedesc = open(MOUSEDEV, O_RDWR );
    while(1) readm();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A mouse tells you nothing except relative position in unspecified units.

You don't need to know.

You just need to decide on a starting point and track position from there.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a [mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_%28computing%29) gives relative movements (this is the way the mouse hardware works), not absolute position.

Use (or at least study) the [GPM](https://freecode.com/projects/gpm) software to use the mouse outside of X.